# How to use Factories injected by Guice in android?

Tags: android, guice, factory

I have problem using Factory injected by Guice.

I've read this nice article http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html but still don't understand something. I.e. why does Module never used? Like in *Guice.createInjector()* method.

I tried this simple application and I have *NullPointerException*, because Guice couldn't resolve Factory I need.

```
public interface FooInterface
{
    String getString();
}

public class Foo implements FooInterface {
    String bar;

    @Inject
    Foo(@Assisted String bar)
    {
        Log.i("main", "Foo constructor");
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getString(){
        Log.i("main", "getString");
        return this.bar;
    }
}

public interface FooFactory
{
    FooInterface create(String bar);
}
```

Here is configuration Module

```
public class ConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        Log.i("main", "Configuration module");
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(FooInterface.class, Foo.class).build(FooFactory.class));
    }
}
```

And my Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Inject private FooFactory fooFactory;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i("main", "onCreate");

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Log.i("main", "onClick");
        FooInterface foo = this.fooFactory.create("foo name");
        String str = foo.getString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String is: "+ str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

As I can see from logs, *Foo* constructor is never called. The same with *ConfigurationModule*. I can't see where this module is used. Any ideas? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Where are you installing your ConfigurationModule? How are you creating your MyActivity activity? (The code you posted looks right, but you do need to make sure you're creating an injector based on the ConfigurationModule and getting an instance of your MyActivity from it.)

Comment: That's the problem that I didn't find in any example how should I use this module. So basically I don't install it at all and don't know how to do that.

I'm not creating activity. Android does. It's my only activity that is launched with application.

Comment: I don't think you can use vanilla Guice on Android. Have you looked into: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki ?

Comment: @condit Yes, I looked into it, and declined it because I use SherlockBar in my app and it's not so easy to get them work together. But if I can't do it on pure Guice, probably I need to spend more time to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all I've read I start thinking that there is no advantages in using pure Guice for Android application. [Roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki) is right choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use ActionBarSherlock as well, look at [roboguice-sherlock](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock).